# SQL Case statement how to get value regardless of other results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN @UserRole = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [CanEdit],
        F.FundingStreamName       
FROM    FundingStream AS F
        LEFT JOIN Projects AS P ON P.FundingStream = F.FundingStreamID 
WHERE   ProjectNumber = @ProjectNumber
```

I noticed if `FundingStreamID` is null, the case statement will return nothing as well, how can I get the case statement to execute regardless if there is a funding stream or not? Thanks.

Comment: In your case use a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks @MicSim you were right, it's a RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `where` clause is "undoing" your left outer join.  Try moving the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @UserRole = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) AS [CanEdit],
       F.FundingStreamName       
FROM FundingStream F LEFT JOIN
     Projects P
     ON P.FundingStream = F.FundingStreamID AND
        P.ProjectNumber = @ProjectNumber ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, when I tried this if P.FundingStream is NULL it will return multiple rows since NULL as opposed to the other answer I put, is there any way to modify yours to not return rows if null?

Answer (score 0):

Using @MicSim answer:

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN @UserRole = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [CanEdit],
        F.FundingStreamName       
FROM    FundingStream AS F
        RIGHT JOIN Projects AS P ON P.FundingStream = F.FundingStreamID 
WHERE   ProjectNumber = @ProjectNumber
```

Thanks again for the help!